# Pdf byte Array to pdf file display inside Android Application

Tags: java, android, file, pdf

I am having a pdf file (Or any kinda file) byte array(coming through web service), which i want to display inside my Android application without getting it downloaded in the memory(Internal/External). I want to support it upto 30MB.

Same feature is getting used by Gmail App, where they are asking for Preview/Save.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You can check a pdf viewer that's working well in this case, it's name is [RadaeePDF](http://www.androidpdf.mobi/)

To open a pdf from remote url:

```
Global.Init( this );
PDFHttpStream m_stream = new PDFHttpStream();
Document m_doc = new Document();
ReaderController m_vPDF = new ReaderController(this);
m_doc.Close();
m_stream.open("http://server/filename.pdf");
int ret = m_doc.OpenStream(m_stream, null);
if( ret == 0 ) {
   m_vPDF.open(m_doc);
   setContentView( m_vPDF );
}
```